Pi4B: picamera2 and gpiozero compatibility?
I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B with a Raspberry Pi Camera Module 2 to take pictures. As a control, I made a program that just detects button presses and prints out that the button has been pressed:
from gpiozero import Button
import signal
import time


lastButtonPress = 0
count = 0


def onButtonPress():
    global count
    global lastButtonPress
    if time.time() - lastButtonPress > 0.5:
        count += 1
        print(f"\nButton Pressed! ({count})")
        last_button_press = time.time()


buttonPin = 23

button = Button(buttonPin)

button.when_pressed = onButtonPress

signal.pause()

This works flawlessly and has no error. However, when I transfer this to code that does essentially the same thing but mixed with the picamera2 module, I get fake button clicks in random moments. Here's my code for that:
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import signal
from gpiozero import Button
import time


lastButtonPress = 0
debouncingTime = 0.5


def onButtonPress():
    global lastButtonPress
    global picam2
    if time.time() - lastButtonPress > debouncingTime:
        picam2.capture_file("test_image.jpg")
        print("\nImage Captured")
        lastButtonPress = time.time()


buttonPin = 23
button = Button(buttonPin)

button.when_pressed = onButtonPress



picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()
picam2.configure(camera_config)
picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
picam2.start()

signal.pause()

I don't know what could be causing problems here, but hopefully, someone knows how I can counteract it. Thank you!

How long are your cables to the button?
